# Create all possible permutations of given variable set

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, set, bioinformatics

I have a problem related to reverse translation.
The problem itself can be stated as: Given character set of 20 unique alphabets(corresponding to 20 amino acids), each alphabet is generated by code composed of 3 characters[any 3 from A,T,G,C]. Generate all the possible nucleotide sequences coding for given amino acid sequence/strings.
There are 64 possible nucleotide[ATGC] combinations for 20 Amino Acids.
For example:Lysine, which is represented by letter K, is coded by two triplets(=codons), AAA and GAA.

Forward translation is fine, since I can just map triplets to Amino acid codes, but the problem is with reverse translation, where various combinations of triplets are possible, since most of the amino acids can be coded by multiple codons.

This is basic skeleton of my program :

```
 //Map all Amino Acids with their corresponding codons.
std::map<std::string, string, std::less<std::string> >  somevar;
somevar["K"]="AAA|GAA";......so on.

//Take input in string of Amino Acid single letter codes.
//Split each Amino acid into corresponding codons using stringstream
while(std::getline(ss, token, '|')){}

//Store the values in vector.
```

First Problem: Since I don't know what will be the size of input string,I need dynamic arrays of vectors or vector of vectors. (To state it simply, If its something like KK occurs, there will be two array type variables storing all triplets for KK.) Is there some way to remove this redundancy(looking directly into some table) ?

```
//Pass the arrays to a function which will return all possible permutations.
```

Second problem: After solving first problem, I want to create all the possible combinations of nucleotide sequence possible with the given amino acid string.(That is, all possible combinations derived from each newly created array(sets)).
KK would result in : AAAGAA,AAAAAA,GAAAAA,GAAGAA.

The only limitation is that the complexity should be ~O(n^2), and I was wondering if I can do it recursively, or if there is some built in function/library in c++ which can help me in generating all possible permutations from given (variable)data set.

Edit: Another example
Say if random letter A have 3 codons, and letter Y have 5, then total number of combinations will be 3*5.

If M=AAT,ATA and N=GTT,AGT,TGT, then the result will be 1)AATGTT,2)ATAGTT,3)AATAGT,4)AATTGT,5)ATAAGT,6)ATATGT

Comment: [std::next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/) may be of use.

Comment: Remember to `std::sort` it before applying `std::next_permutation` such that you won't miss the previous permutations.

Comment: @NickyC, I am looking into std::next_permutation, I am not sure if I can implement it in context to multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @Siddharth just flatten the array representation?

Comment: @larnvst, I need to expand the array regardless, since there exists multiple combinations till n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following may help:

```
std::vector<std::string> translate(const std::vector<std::string>& v,
                                const std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>& mapping)
{
    if (v.empty()) {
        return {};
    }
    std::vector<std::string> res = {""};

    for (const auto& s : v) {
        std::vector<std::string> tmp;

        for (const auto& seq : mapping.at(s)) {
            for (const auto& old: res) {
                tmp.push_back(old + seq);
            }
        }
        res = std::move(tmp);
    }
    return res;
}
```

with:

- `v` the sequence to translate
- `mapping` the mapping between `"K"` and `{"AAA", "GAA"}`

[Live example](https://ideone.com/Gmmdhb)

Comment: The code itself works flawlessly, although I am concerned about the fact that it might not fill the criteria of O(n^2). I think I might be able to modify it a little, but converting it into a recursive function is out of question.

Comment: @Siddharth: Converting the function to recursive won't change the complexity. You have to iterate over a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). You may use an other algorithm to iterate over possibility without generating the whole vector.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to get all permutations (all possible orderings of codons), or all possible translations of letters into codons (more like homophonic substitution)?

If it is the later, for your question 2, the number of output strings will be O(2^n) if all letters have 2 possible codons (much more than O(n^2)).

You can still make it relatively simply with a recursive function (or not, like @Jarod42 did).

For your question 1, I think that the input of your procedure is actually a compact way of storing the output...
Your return type can be `std::vector<std::string>` for one input string, so you can go for `std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >` for all output strings?

Comment: I have edited my question with an example. It can be more or less stated as all possible combinations of codons for that letter, to generate all possible sequences. Much like all combinations between CodonArrayforA[1]*CodonArrayforB[2]

Comment: So I think that @Jarod42's code works correctly for you.

Comment: It is working, but I am still devising an implementation with upper bound at n^2.

Comment: I fear this will not be possible, since the size of your output is `n1*n2*...*nk` if letter `i` has `ni` possible translations.

Comment: I concur, although I did think of something totally different, whereby say, reducing the common codons to reduce degeneracy(If A is codded by GAT and GAA, then reduced form corresponds to GA[X]). This might have reduced computational cost a little, but still wouldn't help in reducing the time complexity. In the end, working with text is always cumbersome.

Comment: You could use binary 0001 for A, 0010 for G, 0100 for C..., and so 0011 for A or G.
To be efficient, you could preprocess your mapping to map letters to codons expressed with these "multiple choice bases" (MCB) instead of original codons.
Using binaries just allow to use only 4 bits for each MCB, but you could stick to characters using your own alphabet.
Anyway, this would require some decoding in the end, so the global complexity will not change?

Comment: Much like Huffman encoding? Size complexity will reduce overall, but the time complexity will remain. And this won't solve the original problem, i.e. large number of redundant codons. I might as well give up on something efficient. Sometimes, problems tend to have difficult solutions.